# Java checking whether the value exists in database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

hello i am working on java and MySQL. My implementation are as follows :

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankingSystem extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        int ur=0;
        int PIN;
        String ID;
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BankingSystem";
        String user = "root";
        String pass="";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Enter Your 4 digit PIN");
        PIN=s.nextInt();

        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from customerinformation where pin ="+PIN);
//checking for existance of user entered pin
if((rs.getString(1)).equals("")){System.out.println("Invalid PIN");}


        while(rs.next())
        {

            System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3)+"  "+rs.getString(4));

        }

    }

}
```

but this code is not working. Giving some sort of exception error but when i remove the line containing if statement then it work fine.How do i check whether the pin is valid or not.

it giving following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.checkRowPos(ResultSet.java:3624)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getString(ResultSet.java:1762)
        at BankingSystem.main(BankingSystem.java:22)
```

Comment: Can you post the exception details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way
Replace this `Statement st = con.createStatement();`
with

```
String query ="select * from customerinformation where pin =?"
PreparedStatement st =con.prepareStatement("query");
st.setInt(1,PIN);
ResultSet resultSet = st.executeQuery();
```

You should never use Statement over PreparedStatement

```
if (!resultSet.next() ) {
    System.out.println("resultset does not data");
} else {

    do {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+"  "+
                           rs.getString(2)+"  "+
                          rs.getString(3)+"  "+
                          rs.getString(4));


    } while (resultSet.next());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if((rs.getString(1)).equals("")){
   System.out.println("Invalid PIN");
}
```

without `rs.next()`, `rs.getString(1)` is not possible

Try this:

```
    if(rs.next()){
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+" "+rs.getString(3)+"  "+rs.getString(4));
    } else {
     System.out.println("Invalid PIN");   
    }
```