# How to check if given atributte is already set in jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

I'm creating Pet Clinic. If the user wants to add new pet he has to input Owner Id. How to check if this Id already exists. If no I want to use the redirect to the new form where the user can add new Owner.

```
    <tr>
         <td><label>Owner: </label></td>
         <td><form:input path="ownerId"/></td>
    </tr>
```

Edit:
I want to check if exists in the database. I have two tables in MySQL. Owner and Pet. Owner can have many Pets, Pet can have just one Owner.

```
Part of Pet Class:



    @Entity
    @Table(name="pet")
    public class Pet {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="id")
        private int id;

        @Column(name="type")
        private String type;

        @Column(name="name")
        private String name;

        @Column(name="sickness")
        private String sickness;

        @Column(name="owner_id")
        private String ownerId;
        ...
}
```

Owner class:

```
    @Entity
@Repository
public class Owner {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;
    ...
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/pet")
public class PetController {

    @Autowired
    private PetService petService;

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String listPets(Model theModel){

        List<Pet> thePets = petService.getPets();

        theModel.addAttribute("pets", thePets);

        return "list-pets";
    }
    ...

   @PostMapping("/savePet")
    public String savePet(@ModelAttribute("pet") Pet thePet){

        petService.savePet(thePet);

        return "redirect:/pet/list";
    }
}
```

Serive

```
@Service
public class PetServiceImpl implements PetService{
   @Autowired
   private PetDAO petDAO;

   @Transactional
    public List<Pet> getPets() {
        return petDAO.getPets();
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void savePet(Pet thePet) {
        petDAO.savePet(thePet);
    }
}
```

DAO

```
@Repository
public class PetDAOImpl implements PetDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public List<Pet> getPets() {

        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Query<Pet> theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("from Pet", Pet.class);

        List<Pet> thePets = theQuery.getResultList();

        return thePets;
    }

    @Override
    public void savePet(Pet thePet) {

        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        currentSession.saveOrUpdate(thePet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your backend code which you have tried. Meaning the code to send the id given in the input box to validate whether it is present in the database or not

Comment: check this link. it gives you an idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583113/java-checking-whether-the-value-exists-in-database

Answer (score 0):

In JSP you can check if object has value with JSTL core lib:

```
<c:if test="${not empty pet.ownerId}">...</c:if>
```

where pet is your model object (passed to form).